# Compare different IPs in two files?

Tags: text-processing, grep, scripting, file-comparison

I have a list from an inventory and another list from management. I'm trying to find the IP's that are similar between both files then output that is similar into another file:

I tried using diff but, the output did not made sense.

```
diff -buy list1 list2
```

then I tried to use  egrep using IP's from list 1but, I think I used the wrong syntax.

```
egrep -o `192.168.*|192.1.69` list2
```

not sure what to use correctly

like:
list 1 maybe have:

```
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
192.168.2.1
```

and I want to try to find this IPs in list2

Comment: Could you please post example data?

Comment: Please edit your post instead of trying to fit it into the comments.

Comment: Yes, please post short sample of inputs and expected output.

Comment: exactly those IP's from list1, or "similar" IP's meaning the same first two octets?

Comment: @JeffSchaller those exact IP's

Comment: @johncasanova I posted an answer, have you seen it?

Comment: @phk yes, I'm trying it out now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution in `bash` or a similar shell with process substitution using the `<(...)` form:

```
comm -1 -2 <(sort list1) <(sort list2)
```

Should you have duplicate entries in `list2` then add the `-u` option to the sort call.